# On click on a button all data resets to 0 in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Form inside, which consists of 3 `buttons` and a HTML table, which I am filling dynamically with JSON data.

**What I am doing:**

I have JSON data for TWO tables with the same structure, that's why I am trying to load the two JSON-Data-Sets into the same `table id` i.e `HourlysalesSummary`. Initially it loads with data `tableData`, then after user clicks on `load Draft` it loads `tableDataDraft`. When the page initially loads up I want to show the data-set `tableData` with `Quantity` field as `0`. Then the user will input something and will be able to `save`. Furthermore there is one more button `save draft`, where the user can save the data into `dataTableDraft`, which I am not including in my code here because it is working fine.

**Now what is my issue:**

- after clicking on load draft data loads from draft table
- after that if the user wants to edit data then he will click on `edit`. On click of `edit` I am loading the `tableDataDraft` table which has `Quantity='0'`
- but here it loads all data  with `0` which I don't want. I want when user clicks on `edit`, the `non-zero` data as well as remaining `0` data.
- in my code I am using `itemsQuantiry=[]` and `itemsQuantiry1=[]` in both data-sets to check if data exists, then show that data otherwise show 0 or (tableData)
- here I am using `autocomplete=on` to store data input fields

**Snippet**

```js
var tableData = [{
    "Item Code": "1000",
    "Item Name": "Coffee-S1",
    "Category Name": "Beverages",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1001",
    "Item Name": "Coffee-S",
    "Category Name": "Beverages",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1083",
    "Item Name": "Oma Stick 200gm",
    "Category Name": "Biscuits",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1387",
    "Item Name": "simple Bhath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1388",
    "Item Name": "Bakala Bhath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },


  {
    "Item Code": "1389",
    "Item Name": "Bisibelebath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "0"
  }
]

var tableDataDraft = [{
    "Item Code": "1001",
    "Item Name": "Coffee-S",
    "Category Name": "Beverages",
    "Quantity": "1213.0000"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1083",
    "Item Name": "Oma Stick 200gm",
    "Category Name": "Biscuits",
    "Quantity": "1478.0000"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1388",
    "Item Name": "Bakala Bhath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "1478.0000"
  },

  {
    "Item Code": "1389",
    "Item Name": "Bisibelebath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "2596.0000"
  }
]

$("#loadDraft").click(function() {
  addTableDraft(tableDataDraft);
  $("#edit").show();
})

var itemsQuantiry = [];

function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Code'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Quantity'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity_field");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        if (itemsQuantiry[i]) {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", itemsQuantiry[i]);
        } else {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        }
        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.value=''");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }

      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  $(".dataReset").on("change", function(e) {
    itemsQuantiry[$(this).attr('index')] = e.target.value;
  });
}
var itemsQuantiry1 = [];

function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
      if (tableData[i]['Item Code'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableData[i]['Item Name'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableData[i]['Quantity'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity_field");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        if (itemsQuantiry1[i]) {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", itemsQuantiry1[i]);
        } else {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        }
        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.value=''");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }
      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  $(".dataReset").on("change", function(e) {
    itemsQuantiry1[$(this).attr('index')] = e.target.value;
  });
}
addTable(tableData);

function editData() {
  addTable(tableData)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form id="indentForm" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="row position-relative">
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Save
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="edit" class="commonButton" onclick="editData()" style="display:none">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Edit
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="loadDraft" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Load Draft
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

- at line no 73 of my js code I am declaring `itemsQuantiry1=[]` globally
- **as I have to upload this large code to run the snippet**, main lines to focus on are: 73, 115, 141 and 183 in my `JavaScript` code
- at all these lines I am checking if value is available, then show that value, otherwise show the quantity of `tableData`

Comment: can you highlight the lines of focus in your code as comment so we can get to it straight ..

Comment: @Haroonnasir done

Comment: yes i have figured out see my answer if thats what you want .

Comment: @Haroonnasir let me try

Comment: @Haroonnasir hey you there? in my code its not working?

Comment: @Haroonnasir it is repeating the data

Comment: @viveksingh Actually, I looked my solution, it's also wrong because you are abusing of javascript untyped variable and everything is messy.

What exactly do you take from AJAX, and what exactly do you want save in AJAX?

Comment: @Crocsx when page loads i am making an ajax call and loading the page then there is button when user clicks on load draft i am loading another data but loading into same table..initially when user loads the page and enter something there is button to view all non zero rows then after clicking view edit shows up and user clicks on edit then it works fine the data remain into the table,but same i am trying to do when user clicks on load draft then if he clicks on edit all data resets to zero

Comment: @Crocsx if you want i can share my full ajax code also

Comment: @viveksingh you are sending your `tableData` data back when you press edit button .. and your tabledata does not have the values that have quantity in them .. if you want to show them both you have to add up the `tableDataDraft`  in it as well

Comment: @viveksingh i have updated my answer please check if it solves your problem

Comment: @Haroonnasir how to add that also?

Comment: @viveksingh i have updated my answer please check .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187717/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-haroon-nasir).

Comment: @Haroonnasir data is repeating sir

Comment: It looks like two answers were given on this page on 1st February, at 07:22 and 07:58. The question was then substantially rewritten - essentially into another question - at 11:06. **Please do not do that**. This has the effect of invalidating the answers given. I have rolled back to the last good version of the question that has been answered. If you have another question, post a new one.

Comment: @halfer ok from now i will keep this in my mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical problem .. just update this in your editData() method

```
 var temptable = [];
 $.each(tableDataDraft,function(index)
  {
    temptable.push(tableDataDraft[index]);
  });
  $.each(tableData,function(index)
   {
    temptable.push(tableData[index]);
   });
```

and you are good to go . 
check this result 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JxWrbd?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

First I would like to say that you should really rewatch your code and make it cleaner, more readable, less all in one.

Your function are 99% the same, you write it twice, just add a parameter and you can take out one of them.

You should also make it more readable by adding smaller function that do specific task (like building a row or a column) instead of putting everything in one huge function.

and for the variables, you are misspelling quantity in all your code to quantiry.

Finally, If I understand your problem correctly, you want the loaded value to remain displayed in the table when you edit it.

like this ? https://codepen.io/crocsx-the-styleful/pen/GzWvaN

If so, your mistake is here

```
if (targetArray[i]) {
  quantityField.setAttribute("value", targetArray[i]);
} else {
  quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
  targetArray[i] = tabledata;
}
```

but you should check if this work as you want (cause it not be working exactly as expected) cause it's pretty hard to understand what you want to achieve and how you are doing it. But basically, you should apply the change to your displayed array when you load it

EDIT : Try this :

https://codepen.io/crocsx-the-styleful/pen/GzWvaN

I do not know what edit should do but,  now you have a variable `currentQuantity` that store all the data for an item ID. I believe from this point you can do what you want. open the console and click edit.

Comment: here only i am writing table code twice in my real code i am am making ajax call and just calling that function inside success

Comment: hey you there i am facing issue while adding your code to my code where i am making ajax call

Comment: what is your problem? and sorry but I also have work to do atm

Comment: ok fine you do your work sir..i ll see your code  then figure out

Comment: @viveksingh try the EDIT codepen, now tho, I really need to go back work.